# Translate "wood stain"

Tags: traducción

I discovered [this article on wood stain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wood_stain), which has no Spanish wikipedia counterpart. While [barniz](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barniz) is the translation of [varnish](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Varnish), there is no Spanish equivalent for "wood stain"? I read [this discussion](http://www.spanishdict.com/answers/164482/would-you-use-tinte-to-mean-wood-stain) but only has 2 responses, one suggests "Colorante para madera" but I can't verify this translation is fit, the other suggests barniz but as I pointed in the beginning, it means varnish, which it's a different thing than wood stain.

Comment: First thing that comes to mind is `tinta`

Comment: Yes, *colorante para madera* is a good translation,  you can say *tinte para madera* too

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As a *weekend woodworker* I use "wood stains" and in Colombia we call those "**tintas**", "**tintes**" o more commonly "**tintillas**".

This are very different from varnish since they are absorbed by the wood and *tiñen = stain* the wood instead of just creating a coating like varnish does.

*Tintillas* are also different from **[primers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primer_(paint))** (*impregnantes*) or **sealers** (*selladores*) because they are not made to protect the wood or to prepare it for the finishing coat but only to give it a specific color and bring out the contrast of its grain.

The left one in the image is a common presentation from my local store. It is alcohol based but there are some other that are in a gel presentation like the one in right image.

[image][image]

The process of using *tintas o tintillas* is called *teñido o entintado* {[Reference](https://www.pintomicasa.com/2013/08/como-tenir-la-madera-paso-a-paso.html)}

> El teñido o entintado es el procedimiento de teñir a la madera natural, sin manos previas, con tintas especiales para este tipo de material, otorgándole un color distinto al original, pero sin tapar la textura y vetas originales de la madera.

I've never used *tintilla a base de agua* (water based stains) but I found some examples of those [here](http://arteyhobby.com/productos/pinturas/para-madera-y-ceramica-al-frio/madetinte/)

[image: Water based stains - tintillas a base de agua]

Comment: Outstanding answer (solution plus documentation).

Answer (score 2):

I'm really not convinced that my answer applies to all countries. But following the links of Wikipedia I see that in French it is known as "lasure". And if so, then it corresponds to what in Spanish (Chilean at least) we know as **impregnante**.

[image]

Comment: as a weekend woodworker I'd say that _impregnates_ are more what in English is called **primers** and not _wood stains_. They work in the same way of being absorbed by the wood but the purpose of primers is to protect the wood and prepare it for the finish coat while the sole purpose of stains is to give it color.

Comment: Judging by the picture of the water on the surface I would say that is more a wood stain than a primer. You would not deliberately get it wet after priming before applying the next coat.